# Using Sql Server for data mining

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-mining

I am working on a project where I am storing data in Sql Server database for data mining. I 'm at the first step of datamining, collecting data. 
All the data is being stored currently stored in SQL Server 2008 db. The data is being stored in couple different tables at the moment. The table adds about 100,000 rows per day.
At this rate the table will have more than million records in about a month's time.

I am also running certain select statements against these tables to get upto the minute  realtime statistics.

My question is how to handle such large data without impacting query performance. I have already added some indexes to help with the select statements.
One idea is to archive the database once it hits a certain number of rows. Is this the best solution going forward?

Can anyone recommend what is the best way to handle such data, keeping in mind that down the road I want to do some data mining if possible.
Thanks

**UPDATE:** I have not researched enough to decide what tool I would use for datamining. My first order of task is to collect relevant information. And then do datamining. 
My question is how to manage the growing table so that running selects against it does not cause performance issues.

Comment: "running selects against it does not cause performance issues" Based on that info: buy enough RAM so that your SQL Server puts the entire table in RAM. A practical suggestion: make the load process as optimised as possible so that it doesn't lock up the table in future. At this stage you have no idea of the required access paths (select statements) so you can't undertake any performance improvements. i.e. you could partition your table, but if your final select does not make use of the partitioned column it won't provide any performance benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What tool you will you be using to data mine? If you use a tool that uses a relational source then you check the worlkload that it is submitting to the database and optimise based on that. So you don't know what indexes you'll need until you actually start doing data mining.

If you are using SQL Server data mining tools then they pretty much run off SQL Server cubes (which pre aggregate the data). So in this case you want to consider which data structure will allow you to build cubes quickly and easily.

That data structure would be a star schema. But there is additional work required to get it into a star schema, and in most cases you can build a cube off a normalised/OLAP structure OK.

So assuming you are using SQL Server data mining tools, your next step is to build a cube of the tables you have right now and see what challenges you have.

Comment: I have not thought about which tool would be used for datamining. My concern is how to manage the data so that it doesnt cause performance issue (slow query & deadlocks). Can you comment on that?

Comment: Based on the information, no. If you had a particular data mining algorithm in mind (see here for some broad classifications http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175595.aspx) then you might be able to optimise the data model for that but then it would be no good for anything else. deadlocks will not be an issue for data mining because you are only reading data. Slow queries can only be fxied by first having the query that is slow and optimising the data for that.